# Rails: Customising SimpleForm Association Wrapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have implemented a search to filter through a list of objects. I would like to apply this filter to a simple form collection using an 'association' type input like the one below.

```
= f.association :fixtures, collection: page.possible_associations, as: :check_boxes
```

I am unsure how to make the collection of objects appear in structure like this

```
%ul#list
  %li
    %div searchable term
      %input
```

My guess is that I can somehow add a custom wrapper tag to the form but looking at the documentation I am a little overwhelmed as to where to start and what to start with.

Thanks in advance.